# ADF af:menu not working in Google Chrome

Tags: oracle-adf

I'm using ADF 12.2.1.0.

I'm building the simple page shown below in which I'm adding an af:menu component on a panelGroupLayout. I'm setting the height of the panel group layout to '2000px' in order to force window scroll.
Google Chrome: the af:menu works fine. Then if I scroll down the page a little bit, the menu doesn't work anymore. The problem doesn't reproduce on Firefox.
Any ideas?

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<f:view xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich">
    <af:document title="untitled1.jsf" id="d1">
        <af:messages id="m1"/>
        <af:form id="f1">
            <af:pageTemplate viewId="/oracle/templates/responsiveTemplate.jspx" id="pt1">
                <f:facet name="header"/>
                <f:facet name="status"/>
                <f:facet name="appNav"/>
                <f:facet name="globalLinks"/>
                <f:facet name="footer"/>
                <f:facet name="center">
                    <af:panelGroupLayout id="pgl3" inlineStyle="height: 2000px;">
                        <af:menuBar id="mb1">
                            <af:menu text="menu 1" id="m2">
                                <af:commandMenuItem text="commandMenuItem 1" id="cmi1"/>
                                <af:commandMenuItem text="commandMenuItem 2" id="cmi2"/>
                                <af:commandMenuItem text="commandMenuItem 3" id="cmi3"/>
                                <af:commandMenuItem text="commandMenuItem 4" id="cmi4"/>
                            </af:menu>
                        </af:menuBar>
                    </af:panelGroupLayout>
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="start"/>
                <f:facet name="end"/>
            </af:pageTemplate>
        </af:form>
    </af:document>
</f:view>
```

Comment: First of all `<af:panelGroupLayout>` will only support the `height`-style when you set `layout="vertical"`, otherwise it will be rendered as an inline tag (i.e. `<span>`). But even then I cannot reproduce the described behavior.

Comment: The problem was related to a known Oracle Bug which was solved by applying the patch P26834987